# How to split a list by a changing step size?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I have a list that I want to split up in to variable steps sizes. For example, if I have a list from 1 to 100, at the end of each iteration, I would want the output to be:

```
[1, 2, 3] 
[4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[9, 10, 11, 12, ..., 15]
[16, 17, ..., 25]
```

The length of the first list is 3, then 5, then, 7, then 9.

What I have is this

```
lst = list(range(1,101))
odd = 3
for i in range(0, len(lst), odd):
    print(lst[i:i+odd])
    odd += 2
```

I know it does not work, but I don't know what needs to change.

Comment: It would seem to me the third list should end with 15, not 16.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the step size varies, you need a while loop:

```
lst = list(range(1,101))
step = 3
idx = 0
while idx<len(lst):
    print(lst[idx:idx+step])
    idx += step
    step += 2
```

Comment: To make this answer more complete, please include how `range(..)`'s step size does not change every iteration..

Answer (score 4):

Note that the indices to begin a slice at are given by the closed form:

```
n**2 - 1
```

Therefore:

```
>>> [lst[n**2-1:(n+1)**2-1] for n in range(1, 10)]
[[1, 2, 3],
 [4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
 [9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
 [16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24],
 [25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35],
 [36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48],
 [49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63],
 [64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80],
 [81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99]]
```

Comment: this is great for the particular example I gave, but what my underlying question was asking how to handle a variable step size

Answer (score 0):

Daniel's answer is the most concise one, but I'd like to point out that sometimes, you have a more complex situation and want to have the same slices from different iterables. Then you can also go along and store the actual `slice(start,stop[,step])` objects that python generates when you write `[start:stop:step]` in a list and use that. E.g.:

```
r1 = range(1,101)
r2 = list(reversed(r1))

slices = [slice(0,5,3)]
for i in range(20):
    slices.append( slice(
                         slices[-1].stop,
                         slices[-1].stop + slices[-1].step + 1,
                         slices[-1].step + 1)
                 )

print [ (r1[s],r2[s]) for s in slices ]
```